# Add pauses in a video file with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editing, video-encoding

Is it possible to add multiple pauses in a video file using ffmpeg?

Example: I would like to add a pause of 3 seconds from 5th second, then a pause of 8 seconds from 17th second.

Audio file syncing is not an issue, just pause should be there at specified intervals.

Comment: See basic method [here](http://superuser.com/q/1071369/114058) in the 1st command. Remove the audii ilters if irrelevant  Also adjust the concat filter to get rid of audio.

Comment: @Mulvya See my answer below, maybe it comes in handy at some point.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the code from [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1071369/ffmpeg-pause-video-every-10-seconds-for-3-seconds) by Mulvya.

If you want to automatically construct the commands, this gets a little more tricky, since you have to calculate frame offsets and stitch the individual filters together. I actually wrote a script that does that, called [`bufferer`](https://github.com/slhck/bufferer). It inserts "fake" rebuffering events into a video file. It also pauses the audio during that time:

```
python bufferer.py -i input.mp4 -b "[[5, 3], [17, 8]]" -v libx264 -a aac -o output.mp4
```

You probably want to modify the script to not include the “spinner” (which is typical for rebuffering online video) and not darken the frame, but this is easy to take out from the functions. (In the future I may provide some options to disable those as well.)